# action_class.class_eval method not working with execute resource's environment property

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have an interesting problem where I refactored a recipe by creating a Chef resource to handle some tasks I may need in other recipes.  For instance, I've created the following action:

```
resource_name :my_command

action :run do
  execute "Execute my command" do
    environment ({"SETTINGS_FOLDER" => node['settings']['folder']})
    command "#{command_exe} -some -params"
  end
end

action_class.class_eval do
  def command_exe
    "#{node['command']['folder']}\\bin\\command.exe"
  end
end
```

When I call `my_command` from a recipe it works as expected. However I have several other `actions` that this resource will implement that'll all use the same `environment`. So what I did was refactor the resource to look like this:

```
resource_name :command

action :run do
  execute "Execute my command" do
    environment env
    command "#{command_exe} -some -params"
  end
end

action_class.class_eval do
  def command_exe
    "#{node['command']['folder']}\\bin\\command.exe"
  end

  def env
    {"SETTINGS_FOLDER" => node['settings']['folder']}
  end
end
```

What happens now is, once `chef-client` executes the `my_command` resource it appears as though the `SETTINGS_FOLDER` environment variable on the machine winds up looking like this:

`SETTINGS_FOLDER = ""C:\my\settings\folder""`

Notice the doubled double-quotes?  I'm not sure why this is happening, but it makes my `command.exe` very angry :(

The `['settings']['folder']` attribute is defined in the cookbook's `attributes/default.rb`like so:

```
default['settings']['folder'] = 'C:\\my\\settings\\folder'
```

My node is running chef-client `13.0.118`

**EDIT** I think the doubled double-quotes was a red herring. I think the logger just represented the hash in that way.  My new thought is that perhaps the `env` method is not being evaluated before being passed to the `environment`, but rather the function reference itself is being passed.  Bear with me, Ruby isn't my first language...

Comment: You've got mismatched quotes in that last example, are you sure that's what you have?

Comment: @coderanger good catch, fixed that up. It is correct in my attributes file, just transcribed it incorrectly here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "env" method name might be a reserved word or is getting stomped later in the run. Try a different name for that method, perhaps?

Comment: You are right! I found this in the `execute` resource documentation: `env is an alias for environment` changing the method name to `enviro` worked